# RemoveListener in Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I have a function that allows the user to capture a polygon.  When the ESC is selected, the polygon closes and a form is displayed allowing user to set color, transparency, etc. Inside my listener after placing the polygon I disabled the listener but everytime I hit the ESC key, I get a new polygon.  Here is my code:

```
        fabric.util.addListener(fabric.document, 'keyup', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                for (var i = 0; i < lineCounter; i++) {
                    mapCanvas.remove(lines[i]);
                }
                //polyPoints.push(new Point(polyPoints[0].x, polyPoints[0].y));
                var poly = buildPoly(polyPoints);
                console.log(poly.get('points'));
                console.log(mapCanvas);

                mapCanvas.add(poly);
                mapCanvas.setActiveObject(poly);
                openObjectPropertiesWindow(winReturn, propertiesOpen, previousSelectedObj, mapCanvas.getActiveObject());
                previousSelectedObj = 'geometry';
                //mapCanvas.renderAll();

                mapCanvas.off('mouse:down');
                mapCanvas.off('mouse:move');
                mapCanvas.off('mouse:up');
                poly = null;
                fabric.util.removeListener(fabric.document, 'keyup', mapCanvas._keyup);
                drawing = false;
            }
        });
```

I have tried several different variations.  How do I disable my listener for the ESC key?

Answer (score 1):

```
fabric.util.removeListener(fabric.document, 'keyup', this.keyup);
```

More information here:
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events

I think where you might be getting it wrong is by trying to reference your `mapCanvas._keyup`. You're extending an object, so use `this`. Also, I don't see a `_keyup` method using the latest version.

Comment: Thanks.  I wound up wrapping the canvas in a div tag with the id of cwrapper.  I was able to add and remove a standard listener on that and not use the fabric.util

Answer (score 1):

This works perfect for me:

```
//This is my listener
canvas.on('object:selected', myFunction);
.
.
//remove the handler to listen to my event
canvas.off('object:selected', myFunction);
```